# I want each of my items in the itemslist to have an image matching to it

Tags: reactjs

I tried this only on the 'Lenovo item' and the image was no rendered.I have the image in my source folder and had it imported in `App.js` component.

```
class ItemsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {total:0,
            items: [
              {image:{image},name:"Lenovo",description:"Core i5 - 4gb ram - 256gb SSD", price: 540},
              {name:"Dell",description:"Core i7 - 8gb ram - 1tb HDD",  price: 700},
              {name:"Asus",description:"Core i3 - 4gb ram - 512gb HDD",  price: 429}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

1)In ItemList Component(I have imported 'logo.svg' image located in your src folder)

```
items: [
    {image:require('./logo.svg'),name:"Lenovo",description:"Core i5 - 4gb ram - 256gb SSD", price: 540},
    {name:"Dell",description:"Core i7 - 8gb ram - 1tb HDD",  price: 700},
    {name:"Asus",description:"Core i3 - 4gb ram - 512gb HDD",  price: 429}
    ]}
```

2) In render function of your ItemList Component,I have added image props

```
render() {
    var theThis = this;
    var items = this.state.items.map(function(item)
     {
      return(
        <Item name={item.name} description={item.description} price={item.price} image={item.image}
        handleShow={theThis.showDetails}
        handleTotal={theThis.calculate}
         />
        );
    });
```

3)In render function of Item Component, i have used img tag to render image

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>


         <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
          <p>{this.props.description}</p>
          <img src={this.props.image} height={50} width={50}></img>
          <button onClick={this.buy}>Buy</button>
          <button onClick={this.show}>Show</button>
          <span> ${this.props.price}</span>
          <span> (Cart: {this.state.amount} items.)</span>
      <hr/>
      </div>
      );
  }
```

Comment: i tried requiring the image and it was not rendered.Importing the image on top of the itemsList component was not possible because the imports only work on the top levels.The image is in the source folder just like App.js component.

Comment: {image:{require('./image.jpg')},name:"Lenovo",description:"Core i5 - 4gb ram - 256gb SSD", price: 540},

Comment: can you show your folder structure(showing where your image is located and ItemList Component)?

Comment: ,can I just simply give you a repo of the project?

Comment: i want all items to have a matching image

Comment: Your repo is empty

Comment: Here is the link    https://github.com/edwin001-tech/Simple-Stocksales-App.git

Comment: It is still a empty repo

Comment: sorry...here is the link   https://github.com/edwin001-tech/Simple-Stocksales-App.git

Comment: its not empty now,i forgot to push it initially.Sorry

Comment: I have edited my answer above(after looking your repo). I have tested it.